# Firebase and ExpressJS serving static resources gives CSS MIME type error

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, handlebars.js

I have some issues with my firebase web project. I'm trying to hook up my firebase hosting site to functions, so that I can covert it into a more dynamic application and use the caching features, that functions provide.

But everytime I try to serve my app my window keeps loading - almost like it's stuck or pulling a large file. Then after a while it comes with an error message for my stylesheets (Bootstrap and a custom sheet)

**Here is a screenshot from Chrome**
[It's the first console message i'm worried about..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm15B.png)

**My code looks like this**
Please note that I'm using handlebars with express. I'm basically following the Firebase own guide for setup: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8&feature=emb_logo

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');
const hbs = require('handlebars');

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
    functions.config().firebase
);

// App settings
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('Misophonia_web/public/public'))
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views','./views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// Routes
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-max-age=600');
    response.render('index.hbs');
});


// Firebase export
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

```css
/* Overall static elements and styles */
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;

    /* Misophonia colors */
    --main-blue-color: #1B508E;
    --miso-white: #fefefe;
    --miso-black: #1b2128;
    --miso-pink: #dbd3d6;
    --miso-dark-blue: #132647;
    --miso-grey: #a2a3a3;

    /* Other colors for designs */
    --main-blue-color: #1B508E;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 115px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 29px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Cookie banner */
#cookie {
    z-index: 2;
}
#cookie-banner {
    background: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height : 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    transition: 500ms;
}

#cookie-banner p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.cookie-button {
    color: var(--miso-white);
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    border: 2px solid var(--miso-dark-blue);
    width: 200px;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.cookie-button:hover {
    opacity: 75%;
}

/* Misophonia front page title styles */
.misophonia {
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 1.5s;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.misophonia:hover {
    color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    transition: 1.5s;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#cover-image {
    background-image: url('../imgs/miso-1.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 1200px;
    transition: 1s;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cover-image:hover {
    background-image: url('../imgs/miso-cover.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 1200px;
}

.vertical-center {
    min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
    min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Text area */
#intro {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

#welcome-header {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.welcome-text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
}

.welcome-text-bottom {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    padding-top: 150px;
}

/* Table of content area */
#tabel-of-content-header h2 {
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--miso-white);
}

#table-of-content {
    background-image: url('../imgs/miso-3.png');
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    transition: 1s;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.content-area {
    background-color: var(--miso-white);
    color: var(--miso-black);
    padding: 15px 25px 10px 25px;
    border: 5px solid var(--miso-dark-blue);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--miso-dark-blue);
}

.content-area p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* Chapter styles */
#chapter-1 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/Noise/noise-hover.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-2 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/the-london-heart/IMG_6444.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-3 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/i-hide/i-hide-gif-1.gif');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-4 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/BLAA/img1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-5 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/nights/IMG_6507.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-6 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/today/today.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

#chapter-7 {
    background-image: url('../imgs/cover/IMG_5307.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: var(--miso-white);
    transition: 2s;
}

.chapter-btn {
    color: var(--miso-white);
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    border: 3px solid var(--miso-dark-blue);
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px var(--miso-dark-blue);
    transition: 500ms;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.chapter-btn:hover {
    opacity: 85%;
}

/* Next button */
.next-button {
    color: var(--miso-white);
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    border: 3px solid var(--miso-dark-blue);
    width: 275px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px var(--miso-white);
    transition: 500ms;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.next-button:hover {
    color: var(--miso-white);
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    border: 3px solid var(--miso-dark-blue);
    transition: 1s;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px var(--miso-dark-blue);
}

/* Footer section */
#footer {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: var(--miso-black);
}

#footer a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--miso-black);
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    transition: 1s;
}

#footer a:hover {
    background-color: var(--miso-dark-blue);
    color: white;
}

/* Media queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    h1 {
      font-size: 45px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 27px;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    .welcome-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .welcome-text-bottom {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #tabel-of-content-header {
        font-size: 27px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    {{!-- <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-145407129-2"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-145407129-2');
    </script> --}}

    <!-- Boilerplate -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/library/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Misophonia_web/public/index.css">
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra|Roboto:400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- AOS scroll -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css"/>
    
    <!-- Page begins -->
    <title>misophonia &bull; misophonia, a visual experience &bull; GO BY LUCK</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="cookie">
    <div id="cookie-banner">
        <p>'misophonia, a visual experience' only uses cookies for analytics purposes. If you wish to learn more, then you can read our cookie policy.</p>
        <a href="./cookies"><button class="cookie-button">READ COOKIE POLICY</button></a>
        <button id="close-cookie-banner" class="cookie-button">THAT'S OK WITH ME!</button>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="cover-image" data-aos="fade-in">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center vertical-center">
        <h1 class="misophonia">misophonia</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="intro">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-3" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h1 id="welcome-header">misophonia, <br> a visual experience</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" data-aos="fade-in">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10">
                <div>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        If you’re reading this, it means that misophonia has officially been released from its digital cage and is now living in the world around us.
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        It’s been 3 years since I first sat down in my small bedroom in East London and started recording what has now grown to become a full-length hour-long album, ‘misophonia’. It’s been a long, fragile, powerful but extremely inspiring process to make this record. I hope you find that it sounds unique and personal.
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        With ‘misophonia’ the idea was always to experiment a lot, especially with creating different universes and sonic worlds, from old home-recorded samples, vocals as well as hard (and soft) synthesizers. I would like to believe that misophonia is a pretty vivid and texturized album full of perfect imperfections. 
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        The point of this website is to be a hyperzine. A place that acts as a 'behind-the-scenes' and tells the story of ‘misophonia'.
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        Thank you for your time and for listening to ‘misophonia’.
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text">
                        Yours sincerely, <br>
                        Gustav <br>
                        GO BY LUCK <br>
                    </p>
                    <p class="welcome-text-bottom">
                        Ps. <br> This site is best experienced on a full-scale browser. Should you visit it on your phone, then please try not to go too far and use a full-scale browser instead. <br> I promise it will be worth it.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="table-of-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 mt-3 mb-2" id="tabel-of-content-header">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <h2>TABLE OF CONTENTS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="./noise"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary next-button mb-5">Start Chapter I</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-1">
                <h3>Chapter I</h3>
                <h4>misophonia is noise</h4>
                <p>Noise is everything in misophonia</p>
               <a href="./noise"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-2">
                <h3>Chapter II</h3>
                <h4>The heart of London</h4>
                <p>London: throwback</p>
                <a href="./london"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-3">
                <h3>Chapter III</h3>
                <h4>'I hide'</h4>
                <p>'I hide' <br> (the super secret long version)</p>
                <a href="./hide"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-4">
                <h3>Chapter IV</h3>
                <h4>BLAA, BLUE, Blå</h4>
                <p>Blue photos</p>
                <a href="./blaa"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-5">
                <h3>Chapter V</h3>
                <h4>the night I wrote 'Point & Shoot'</h4>
                <p>All night I wrote</p>
                <a href="./nights"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-6">
                <h3>Chapter VI</h3>
                <h4>Today, tomorrow</h4>
                <p>It's not time to say goodbye</p>
                <a href="./today"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4 d-flex justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-in">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 content-area mt-3" id="chapter-7">
                <h3>Chapter VII</h3>
                <h3>Sleeve notes</h3>
                <p>Thank you!<br> and bye-bye!</p>
                <a href="./sleeve-notes"><button class="chapter-btn">GO TO CHAPTER</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="footer">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-left">
        <a href="./cookies">Cookie & privacy policy</a>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="../js/mobile/mobile-detection.js"></script>
<script src="../js/cookie-banner.js"></script>
<!-- Obligatory bootstrap code -->
<script src="../js/library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- AOS Scroll -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!